# Runas my own user (for network configuration operations)

Tags: windows, runas

I am not an administrator of my corporate laptop, but I belong to the "Network Configuration Operators" group. With that permission I can change the IP address and routes.

For it to work the process has to be in a kind of user-elevated mode (not plain user, not administrator).

I have a BAT script that changes routes, and the way it works is:

1. Right click -> Run as Administrator
2. Use **my own user** (yes, the same plain user i was, not "administrator")
3. The script runs fine

That works fine, but i'd like to skip the right clicking.

I thought that "runas" command would work, but it doesn't get enough elevation.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Powershell's `Start-Process` can do what `runas` can't.

`powershell Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath MyCommand`

If I run the program like that (it's actually a WSL script) it gets enough elevation to be able to change the routes.

I feel like there should be options in both commands, so I can tell whether I want elevation or not.